# VBA Macro to run on a specific worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to have a macro to run for a specific worksheet only. The purpose of the macro would be to look for a specified range and find negative values and if there is any to extract the whole row into a new worksheet and at the same time transform those negatives to positives. I came up with some but i know for sure that this is totally wrong...missing a lot of stuff. Still trying to learn, new to this vba stuff. Thanks in advance for any help that you can provide. fyi ntp stands for negativestopositives. Not sure if that will help, just thought i can write all the details to my small "code"

```
Sub ntp()
Dim ws As Worksheet
If ws.Name <> "originalNeg" Then
    For Each Cell In Range("I2:I1048576")
        If Cell.Value < 0 Then
            Cell.Value = Abs(Cell.Value)
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub ntp()
Dim ws      As Worksheet
Dim cel     As Range
With Activeworkbook.Worksheets("originalNeg")
    For Each cel In .Range("I2:I" & .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
        If cel.Value < 0 Then cel.Value = Abs(cel.Value)
    Next cel
End With
End Sub
```

This uses the worksheet, and note the `.` before `Range()` which links the range to that specific sheet.

Also, only rarely would you want to use *all* cells in a column. I used the `.End(xlUp).Row` to get the last used row in Column I for you to loop through.

Comment: `Rows.Count` ?  Unqualified?!?!?!  Come on, an extra `.` isn't too much effort to type.

Comment: @YowE3K - I've actually been pondering myself - with `Rows.Count`, wouldn't it **always** be the same? I agree that the, hm, where is it? ah, `.` isn't that hard to type. But I consciously left it out here to almost bait \*someone\* to comment, so I could ask. ...So, does `Rows.Count` unqualified actually matter ever, or slow things down? :D

Comment: Actually, given that you have an unqualified `Worksheets`, and therefore you are referring to a worksheet in the `ActiveWorkbook`, which is therefore the same workbook as `ActiveSheet`, in this case it **won't** matter.  But if the active workbook was an `xlsx` file and the worksheet you were referring to was in a `xls` file, then `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count` would be `1048576` and the sheet being processed would only have `65536` rows - thus giving a 1004 error.  (And, if the files were the other way around, you might miss row 1000000 being used because you went up from 65536.)

Comment: I just like always using it so that it doesn't come back to bite people once they start working on multiple workbooks - get them into the habit from the start and we end up with less questions to answer.  (And, FWIW, I had to ask the same question as you just asked about a year ago, and I think it was Tim or Scott who had to explain it to me.)

Comment: @YowE3K - Ohhh, the `xlsx` vs `xls` is a great point!  I'll keep it unqualified here, just to keep these comments on-point, but I'll qualify my `Rows/Columns.Count` in the future.  (Also thanks for reminding me to qualify the `Worksheets`, I edited that in).  Excellent points, cheers! :D

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys. This is so useful. Would you be able to teach me on how to add an extra code in there so instead of changing those negative values to positive in the same sheet, it can add an extra sheet to the work book, paste the same data but instead of negative values , convert everything to positive. @BruceWayne

Comment: Also if you can help as well that would be much appreciated. Both of you guys are great @YowE3K

Comment: @OneaboveAll That should be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("originalNeg")
```

instead of the if on the name.

Comment: At the moment, `ws` is not being used anywhere in the code.  There is no point in `Set`ting it unless you also suggest a change to the rest of the code to use it (i.e. `ws.Range`).